# interval of the horizontal axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, axis

I want to add a custom interval to the x-axis for the graph attached.It should be start from 20, and then increased by 5. For example, 20, 25, 30, ......50. Similar question was asked before, but it was closed without any answer. Thank you so much in advance. My code is depicted below.

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{centering}
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5cm}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{axis}[
    footnotesize,
    xbar, 
    width=11.0cm, height=4.5cm, 
    enlarge y limits=0.01,
    enlargelimits=0.07,  
    %xlabel={\#participants},
    symbolic y coords={Al, Stor, Pro, Ser, Domain, Services},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
]
    \addplot coordinates {
    (48,Services) (27,Domain) (26,Ser) (25,Pro) (23,Stor) (37,All)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\caption{Design}
%\end{adjustwidth}
\label{fig:SQ21}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: just add `xmin=20` and `xtick distance=5` to the `axis` options.

Comment: Akha, thanks. It was so sample :-) Regards

Comment: You are welcome. Do you want to delete the question or shall I write an answer?

Comment: Please write the answer. Would be better for someone else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comment below the question, simply add `xmin=20` and `xtick distance=5` to the `axis` options to achieve what you want.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        footnotesize,
        xbar,
        width=11.0cm, height=4.5cm,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % added
        xmin=20,
        xtick distance=5,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        enlarge y limits=0.01,
        enlargelimits=0.07,
        symbolic y coords={All, Stor, Pro, Ser, Domain, Services},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (48,Services) (27,Domain) (26,Ser) (25,Pro) (23,Stor) (37,All)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]